# Play Video in Javafx (Ubuntu)

Tags: javafx

my code id

```
public class Video1 extends Application {

private static String arg1;

@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Media Player");

// Create media player

    Media media = new Media("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/VideoPaly/src/videopaly/vid.flv");

    javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

// Print track and metadata information
    media.getTracks().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Track>() {
public void onChanged(Change<? extends Track> change) {
            System.out.println("Track> "+change.getList());
        }
    });
    media.getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String,Object>() {
public void onChanged(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Object>   change) {
            System.out.println("Metadata> "+change.getKey()+" -> "+change.getValueAdded());
        }
    });

 // Add media display node to the scene graph
    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
    root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
if (args.length > 0) {
        arg1 = args[0];
    }
    Application.launch(args);
}
}
```

I want to Play Video From Resource of Ubuntu when i run above code it give error like  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! at line

```
Media media = new Media("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/VideoPaly/src/videopaly/vid.flv");
```

any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

From JavafX2  [Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29) Class constructor doc :

> Constructs a Media instance. This is the only way to specify the media
>   source. The source must represent a valid URI and is immutable. **Only
>   HTTP, FILE, and JAR URLs are supported**. If the provided URL is invalid
>   then an exception will be thrown
>
> **Throws**:
>       **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException** - if the **URI string does not conform to RFC-2396** or, if appropriate, the Jar URL
>   specification, or is in a non-compliant form which cannot be modified
>   to a compliant form.

so your source uri should be like this :

> file://path to your media